# ssis get 3 row and all the data from 9 row

Tags: ssis

in my csv file data is like this

***************** file format***************************

filename, abc

date,20141112

count,456765

id,1234

,,

,,

,,

name,address,occupation,id,customertype

sam,hjhjhjh,dr,1,s

michael,dr,2,m

tina,dr,4,s

***********************more than 30000 records in each load ***************************************

i have got the file in above format and i want to take date and count from 2nd and 3rd row and than the data starts from 9th row. is it possible without script task i am not so good with scripting

can anyone plz help how t get this.

Answer (score 0):

With out using a script task also it is possible to do. The flow is like...
Pull 2 DFT into your package, 1 to reformat your text file and split it to 2 separated text file. 1 for your 2nd & 3rd row and another 1 for more the 9th row. The another DFT will do your rest operation which is quite simple.

```
 1st DFT--> Flat file source--> Row Number Transformation (You can get this new           transformation from this link as per your sql version <http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.in/p/ssis-addons.html>) -->conditional split (1-->RowNumber == 2 || RowNumber == 3,2-->RowNumber > 8)-->Put the result into 2 different flat files _1 & _2 as per your convenience naming.
```

Now you are ready with your required 2 flat files as source to your 2nd DFT...

*If it solves your problem, mark it as answer.